# Error compiling class that contains trait in groovy

Tags: java, scala, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I have a module which uses Groovy (2.5.14) and Scala (2.11.6). All the dependencies are maintained by gradle (ver 6.x). While building the project I am getting some strange compilation Error as shown below:

> [Error] Class A.B.C$Trait$FieldHelper not found - continuing with a stub.
> (where C is some trait)

To be precise, while build the module, the task `compileTestScala` fails with the above error.

Here is the snapshot of the build gradle

```
compileTestScala {
classpath = classpath.plus(files(compileTestGroovy.destinationDir))
dependsOn compileTestGroovy
}

compileScala {
classpath = classpath.plus(files(compileGroovy.destinationDir))
dependsOn compileGroovy
}
```

However, the compileScala builds successfully. What could be the root cause?

Comment: Does the error happen when you invoke `compileTestGroovy` directly, as opposed to transitively by way of `compileTestScala`?

Comment: `compileTestGroovy` gets build successfully when it is invoked directly. But when `compileTestScala` is invoked, it fails.